# Is there a way of editing crontabs without using vi?

Tags: cron

The standard way of crontabs -e is ok, but it would be nice if could do edits using nano, or perhaps just using echo from the shell, for inserting new cron jobs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the editor that you want to use to edit your crontabs using `export VISUAL=nano; crontab -e`. Also, each user's crontabs can be found in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` and there's various cron files and folders in `/etc` with `/etc/crontab` being the global crontab file.

Comment: I put `export VISUAL=nano; ` in `~/.bashrc` as an environmental variable and just do `crontab -e`. Works well, thanks.